# remove/delete any nth Node in LinkedList Java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

i would like to know how delete any nth Node in a LinkedList for example:

1-2-3-4-5-6-
after remove any n=2:
1-3-5-
or n=3:
1-2-4-5

thanks!

Comment: .remove(index) does not work?

Comment: Javadoc : [remove(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(int))

Comment: If you are not using inbuilt class `LinkedList` then this link will be helpful for you (you just have to generalise for n>2):
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-alternate-nodes-of-a-linked-list/

Comment: Your comment to both working solutions is not clear. If you are using java 8 it cannot be simpler than D_plus_plus's one. If this is not what you are after please explain much clearer what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Java 8 do as follows:

```
linkedList.removeIf((i) -> i % n == 0);
```

Example:

```
int n = 2;
LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6));

ll.removeIf((i) -> i % n == 0);
System.out.println(ll);
```

Comment: we still not allowed to use LinkedList<Integer>
we build the linkedlist

Answer (score 0):

I believe the confusion came from the fact that it was not made very clear that you want to remove **every nth element as it was in the initial** list and I think this is why the question was down marked.

However here is one way of doing it:

```
public class ListRemover<T> {
    public void removeEvery(int n, List<T> list) {
        int i = 1;
        int removeFrom = n - 1;
        while (removeFrom < list.size()) {
            list.remove(removeFrom);
            ++i;
            removeFrom = n * i - i;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the test for every second and ebery third removal proving it works:

```
public class ListRemoverTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldRemoveEverySecondElement() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> intList = IntStream.range(1, 10).boxed().collect(toList());
        new ListRemover<Integer>().removeEvery(2, intList);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), intList);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRemoveEveryThirdElement() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> intList = IntStream.range(1, 10).boxed().collect(toList());
        new ListRemover<Integer>().removeEvery(3, intList);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8), intList);
    }
}
```

Comment: we still not allowed to use LinkedList<Integer>
we build the linkedlist